# How to use google rest console with salesforce rest API

Tags: rest-api, webservices, chrome

Hi I wanted to  test my rest webservice from Google Rest API Console earlied I did this by copy pasting session from VF page in same browser.  I feel this should be directly possible can anybody suggest a better approach ?

Answer (score 5):

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2012/12/oauth-20-salesforce-using-rest-console.html

Blogged the whole set up procedure step by step above an year back.

Using oauth we will obtain the oauth token which will long lost till the session expires and hence you need not each time copy paste .

Session settings holds this time .If session expire you need to get oauth token again for testing your webservices .