# How can we get access token url and authorize url in rest console oAuth authorization?

Tags: rest-api, oauth, authentication

[image]

I am new i rest api and salesforce. I am trying to connect rest console with salesforce. For setting oAuth authorization i need access token url and authorize url. Where would i get these values from ? I have attached the screen shot. plz help..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working this out using existing Questions here on this board like this? :

[How to use google rest console with salesforce rest API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20862/how-to-use-google-rest-console-with-salesforce-rest-api)